# React-native Timeout when connecting to remote debugger in windows

Tags: android, react-native, remote-debugging, react-native-debugger

I am new to React-Native and android app development as a whole. While i try to run remote debugger in Android Emulator (Pixel 2 phone), I get the following error in the emulator: [image: Error on Emulator]

Then after, even if I stop remote debugging, the application won't run on the emulator (i.e. nothing is rendered into the emulator screen). I need to run the project again.

Following is the auto-generated debugger URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/debugger-ui

How can I Fix this problem?

Comment: Try running ’react-native start’ in a separate command/terminal window and them when debugger started successfully run your app in a separate window.

Comment: Whenever i manually insert the URL: http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ and then re-run the application using react-native run-android , and then start debugger it works. Otherwise in case of the  auto-generated debugger URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/debugger-ui, it deos not work!! I tried changing default debug server URL, but then it throws some new error along the way.. what can i do here?

Comment: same as above, using React Native 0.55. got URL 10.0.2.2:8081/debugger-ui and timeout,  use localhost and it work

Comment: Please use http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/ instead of http://10.0.2.2:8081/debugger-ui  the React Native version is 0.55.4.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

http://10.0.2.2:8081/debugger-ui This is internal IP  the Android VM, with your browser use `localhost:8081/debugger-ui` reference https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16674#issuecomment-376774645

Answer (score 1):

uninstall your application, then run => `react-native run-android` in terminal then click debugging end in chrome replace `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/`, end run react-native run-android. if you still haven't succeeded try again