# Android Emulator cannot connect to React-Native remote debugger - Timeout while connecting

Tags: debugging, react-native, android-emulator, expo

Im trying to connect to the remote debugger using Android Emulator (Pixel XL API 28) and regardless of attempts I get the error message:

```
Unable to connect with remote debugger  
Timeout while connecting to remote debugger
```

The URL that Chrome opens appears correct: localhost:19006/debugger-ui
But the application always errors and will not connect.
I have tried the solution posted in [React-native Timeout when connecting to remote debugger in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234795/react-native-timeout-when-connecting-to-remote-debugger-in-windows)  with no luck.  And most of the other SO questions do not match the issue I am encountering.

RN version: 0.52.0
Chrome Version: 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build)(64-bit)
Android Emulator: Pixel XL API 28
Using the Expo XDE IDe if it matters?

[[image: Emulator Error Message]]
[image: Debugger Browser]

Comment: You open the debugger by yourself or it automatically opens when your app start?

Comment: @JoseVf - I'm pressing Ctrl-M on the emulator and selecting `Debug JS Remotely`

Comment: :/ I asked because (IDK why..) sometimes when I debug the IP and Port changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the debugger first (before run) in your browser, then run on emulator, and choose "debug JS Remotely"

Comment: Same results when I try this